# Algebraic numbers and algebraic functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-number-theory

If $f : \bar{\mathbb{Q}} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is a continuous function, where $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ denotes the set of algebraic numbers, does such function have to be constant?

Comment: What topology are you using for $\overline\Bbb Q$? For example if you have an embedding of $\overline\Bbb Q$ into $\Bbb C$ and you use the subspace topology, then $f(z) = \Im z$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Usual topology @GregMartin

Comment: More generally any polynomial with algebraic coefficients is continuous, and even continuous for all the possible nonarchimedean topologies too.

Comment: @TokenToucan But the range of the function shall be contained in $\mathbb{Q}$, not in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer ahh didn't spot that!

Comment: @GregMartin The range of your example function includes irrational numbers, so it does not serve as a counterexample unless I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

The claim is actually false. Proffering the following counterexample
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\ \text{if the real part of $x$ is greater than $\pi$, and}\\
0,&\ \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: First I tried to prove the claim when the domain is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. Then I came up with the same counterexample using $\sqrt3$ instead of $\pi$. After a few more minutes I saw the light.

Answer (score 1):

> can such function be constant?

I assume you mean "does it have to be constant?". No, it doesn't.

> **Lemma.** There is a non-constant continuous function $f:X\to Y$ between any countable metrizable space $X$ with at least two points *and* any topological space $Y$ with at least two points.

*Proof.* If $X$ has an isolated point, say $x_0$, then we can simply glue any value on $\{x_0\}$ with any other constant value on $X\backslash\{x_0\}$. The "glueing" is done via [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma).

If $X$ does not have an isolated point then by the famous Sierpiński theorem $X$ is homeomorphic to the standard $\mathbb{Q}$, and thus there is a non-constant continuous function to $Y$ because we can partition $\mathbb{Q}$ into two disjoint closed subsets and again apply the pasting lemma on constant pieces. $\Box$

So assuming you deal with the standard $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is a countable subspace of complex numbers (and thus metric), then the answer is that there are such non-constant continuous functions.

Of course the Sierpiński theorem I used is highly non-trivial, but on the other hand it covers a very wide range of cases.